# c++ - QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I created a working QListWidget with multiple items, but I can't figure out how to make it user-friendly. It looks like this:

```
1000
1001
1002
...
```

But I want it to look like this, where firt 4 numbers have a meaning, while all the rest info is just for user.

```
1000 Name LastName and some other helpful info
1001 tom jeff smallville
1002 ming vase, 1992
...
```

For example, this line

```
fotoId = ui->devices->currentItem()->text().toInt();
```

should give me same result in both cases.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @user You'll need to explain your question better

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [QAbstractItemModel::setData()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) with custom role ID.

```
const int CustomRole = Qt::UserRole + 1; // enum should be better for multiple user role
...
// set values
listWidget->model()->setData(index1, 1000, CustomRole);
listWidget->model()->setData(index2, 1000, CustomRole);
...
// get value
int value = listWidget->model()->data(index1, CustomRole).toInt(); // should be 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to store the string as you want to display it inside the widget and parse the result when retrieving it, or implement the data() method yourself (using Qt::DisplayRole).